# Be more specific in what has failed c# ef4.0

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

How can i be more specific in what has fialed ie how would i report back that is the username or password failed and not just report back failed.

So i can return username was correct but password was not

```
   ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /// <summary>  Validates the user. </summary>
        ///
        /// <remarks>  Dave, 2/15/2014. </remarks>
        ///
        /// <exception cref="EntityContextException">  Thrown when an Entity Context error condition
        ///                                            occurs. </exception>
        ///
        /// <param name="username">    The username. </param>
        /// <param name="password">    The password. </param>
        ///
        /// <returns>  The NaviHrUsers. </returns>
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        public NaviHrUsers ValidateUser(string username, string password)
        {

            try
            {
                NaviHrUsers currentUser = naviEntities.NaviHrUsers.FirstOrDefault(r => r.login == username && r.password == password);

                if (currentUser != null)
                {
                    return currentUser;
                }

                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new EntityContextException("ValidateUser failed.", ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why you want something like that ? This could let some attacker to figure out your usernames and then, he/she can try different passwords for the same username.

Comment: As others have said, don't do this. But if you are determined, you could query on username, if that fails you know username is wrong, if it succeeds, then check the password

Answer (score 2):

It's poor security practice to let a user know the the username was correct but the password was incorrect. That gives an attacker the ability to guess the password again.

Comment: Also, please don't be storing the password as plain text.